# Row extending outside of it's container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this weird problem with my bootstrap row and I can't figure it out..
If you take a look at this image you see that my row is extending outside of my container fluid for some reason. I applied only one style to container fluid which is `max-width: 1600px` and `padding:0`. However, I don't think this is the problem.

[image]

Here's how I have my footer structured. As I said, no extra styles applied to the .row itself..

```
<!-- Start Footer area -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Quick Links</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="register-link" href="#"><button class="footer-register-btn" type="button">Register</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-devider">
  <p class="copyright">Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved. Proiect de licenta</p>
</div>
<!-- End Footer area -->
```

Comment: Please, create a code snippet. I've tried to run your HTML on https://jsfiddle.net and seen no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out.. The problem was with the fact that I had no padding on the container-fluid. After I added some left and right padding it worked.